# Java .War file deletion

Tags: java

I have a .war file in my File system.I tried to delete as follows,

```
private void deleteWar(File warFile){       
 if(warFile.list().length != 0){
    String files[] = warFile.list();
    for (String temp : files) {                 
            File fileDelete = new File(warFile, temp);                  
            deleteWar(fileDelete);
    }               
    if(warFile.list().length==0){
        warFile.delete();
        System.out.println("Directory is deleted : " + warFile.getAbsolutePath));        
         }
     }              
 }
```

but i couldnt able to delete .war file as java.io.File.So is there any way to delete a .war file.

Thanks

Comment: try with native commands

Comment: what you trying to do, actally? Undeploy application? Simple delete file with .war extension?

Answer (score 2):

The only code you need is `warFile.delete()`.

There's no point in trying to list the contents of the .war file as though it was a directory. It isn't.

Just delete the file. If it is open or locked or you don't have permission, it may fail, so investigate that.

Comment: I think it is locked because the war is in use by a web-container.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach Curiouser and curiouser. Maybe the web-app is trying to delete itself ;-)

Comment: Mission Impossible: "This war-file will delete itself, after deployment."

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just open `het parent directory` of the War file and remove the file? It seems you are trying to delete the war directory after expansion in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the *absolute path* of the file.

Example:

> C:/Users/Ryan/Downloads/someWarFile.war

I recreated the problem, and this code deleted the .war file.

Code:

```
        String file = "C:/Users/Ryan/Downloads/someWarFile.war";
        File f = new File(file);

        if( f.exists() )
            System.out.println(file + " exists.");
        else
            System.out.println(file + " not exists.");

        if( f.delete() ) 
            System.out.println(file + " has been deleted");
        else
            System.out.println(file + " could not be deleted");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are many problemsb deleting a war file.

I assume you are running a web-application-container like tomcat or jetty.
If you are running this container at a windows-maschine, the war-file my be locked by windows and you are unable to delete the file while the container is running.

Try anti-war file locking in the tomcat-container: 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

Search for resource locking.

As @EJP mentioned: file.delete() is all you should need.